# How to get bestseller in left column layout in Magento 2.2.0?

Tags: magento2.2.0, best-seller

I want to display bestseller products just below the compare product list. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `after` attribute with your block/container that you are using for bestseller products in your layout.
for eg:

```
<referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
     <block class="Namespace\Module\Block\YourBlockClass" name="xyz" after="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="your/template/path.html" />
</referenceContainer>
```

Note `after="catalog.compare.sidebar"` here, the name `catalog.compare.sidebar` is block name of compare product sidebar.

Or even you can use `move` tag to put your block after compare product side bar

`<move element="your.block.name" destination="sidebar.additional" after="catalog.compare.sidebar" />`